# Whats the Vi command to delete a line from a file from a user input?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, line

I have a file and want to delete lines when user enters an ID in UNIX/Vi.

The file is called 'users' and contains:

```
001:joe:one:20:01:02 
002:joe:two:21:06:02
003:joe:three:22:05:02
004:joe:four:23:04:02
```

I have used the following function in Vi:

```
 function deleteRecord()
  {

    echo "Please enter staff ID: "
    read userID

#store staffID in variable
    sID=$( grep -w "$userID" users )

    #store staff details only if user does not exist
    #else prompt them to input again until they enter unused data
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
            echo "Sorry that user does not exist!"
            echo "Try entering a different staff ID to delete"
            deleteRecord
    elif [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
                    #:g/^$userID:/d

                    #sed /$userID/d users >tmp
                    #imv tmp users
                    echo "You have successfully deleted the user."
                    sleep 2
                    mainMenu
   fi

 }
```

I have tried that but it does not work! Is sed the problem?

Please help.

Comment: Just to add the 001, 002 etc are the user IDs (userID)! :)

Comment: Unix 'vi' editor does not accept function declarations as you show. I think you want to retag this as 'vim' editor. Good luck.

Comment: Thought vi was vim and vice versa? Thanks.

Comment: @Design Loper: Vim is "VI iMproved", and while it's based on VI it now has a lot more functionality. They are not the same. (Although Vim does have a VI-compatibility mode).

Comment: @DesignLoper:  Your function may have been edited using the Vim editor, but it is not "written in or for Vim".  It looks like a bash script to me, and other than fact that you used Vim to type the lines of the script it has nothing at all to do with Vim, it could have been typed in using any text editor.  That explains why you can't make heads or tails of Mr E's answer.  You'll get better answers if you tag your question as "bash", "shell", and "sed" related.

Comment: Ok guys ...thanks. Yes its a bash script....and was created by typing  'Vi appSys' in unix. So is this vim or vi? Thanks.

Comment: @design-loper: You're using `vi` as an editor, but that's not relevant. It's a `bash` script.

Comment: Desin-loper: It's the same when you ask: How to cook a chili with MS-Word? (Because you wrote a recipe with MSWord). :) Simply a recipe is the script, the "/bin/bash" is your owen, and vi is your "MSWord".

Comment: OK. Any one know whats the error though? Thanks.

Comment: The first condition works...upto redirecting the user back to the function to enter a user ID. Doing:

Comment: "it does not work! " That's useless information. Tell us what's happening, and what you expect. And put this in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only for fun - here is your homework. Next time tag it.

```
#!/bin/bash
IDFILE="./testfile"
function killVogon() {
while read -p 'Enter Vogon-ID (or "q" for return) >' id
do
    case "$id" in
        (q|Q) return;;
    esac
    grep "^0*$id:" "$IDFILE" >/dev/null 2>&1
    case $? in
        (0) ;;
        (1) echo "Although it is infinitely improbable, the '$id' does not exists!"; continue;;
        (*) echo "You're blind and can't see any Vogons around"; sleep 1 ; return;;
    esac
    sed -i '.bak' -e "/^0*$id:/d" "$IDFILE"
    case $? in
        (0) echo "The Vogon is successfully killed"; sleep 1; return;;
        (*) echo "Huh... Marvin, powered with pangalactic gargleblaster is too paranoid now. The Vogon is NOT killed" ;;
   esac
done
}
killVogon
```

Comment: Hey mr 'Vogon' Your a Pro! Thanks! The error now is                  sed: cant read the .bak file file or directory. Do I have to create this in the home or current dir? Even though it still deletes the user!

Comment: remove the '.bak'.e.g.: sed -i -e "/^0*$id:/d" "$IDFILE" - will do inplace editing without backup file. alternatively you can cp "$INFILE" /tmp; before sed.

Comment: Thank you buddy! How long have you scripting for then? !

Answer (score 1):

You're best off using the [built in functionality](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#multi-repeat). e.g.

```
:g/^theuserid:/d
```

Comment: Without out sed or mv? Thanks!

Comment: Try it out...you could wrap it in a function if you wanted.

Comment: Tried it...but didn't work! The program just exited. Your the pro...what do you think is wrong? Thanks again

Comment: I think there could be a problem with the names of the variables? Seems like the logic aint right somehow somewhere....This is where I need a pro's help :)

Comment: I meant, just open the file, type `:` then `g/^004:/d` to delete user four.

Comment: The user cannot open the file. They are meant to just type a user ID and the function should delete the line containing user ID they typed from the users file. Hope that helps...thanks.

Comment: Its part of a bigger system....if that helps. The user ID is entered outside of Vim. :)

Comment: I see. You mean you have an admin system in Vim? That's awesome.

Comment: Yeah...kind of...Thanks. Just a small appraisal system. Nothing more. I've only been doing UNIX 1month now and I love it.

Comment: Aha, well I'm not quite sure what's not working with your example. Suggest you try a simplified version first to diagnose. What's happening with sID though?

Comment: sID is just there to keep a temporary value of the user ID if it exists in the users file. However it does not work without it and also does not matter if its there.

Comment: Please check the original question again...Ive edited the function.

Comment: Thanks Mr E for your help! Found the solution below.